# Workbox-build doesn't add to service worker **some** of precache urls (but does add others)

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have an Angular 8 project which after building with angular-cli outputs to several bundle files:

```
chunk {0} 0.86bbf5c9edb63f626a71.js () 45.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} runtime.b7f5cba16f3e526a1461.js (runtime) 2.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.2ecd18f83cbcdc2f41b1.js () 30.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3.3c6f6cac43c897221001.js () 66.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} common.47e8c0f35a6b18d38d74.js (common) 3.78 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.a2ada2def205b6dd2266.js () 2.1 MB  [rendered]
chunk {6} main.7eef8fe96731a01550cd.js (main) 416 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {7} polyfills.ad9a67987ca4da80a52a.js (polyfills) 36.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {8} styles.8727807d7b65fa51a4c7.css (styles) 598 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {9} vendor.17d6b0cb2434f0d8397d.js (vendor) 2.87 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {10} 10.f7fd6c136990dd6fca53.js () 571 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11.6d02f073f8b0d383d045.js () 19.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} 12.84e1a02b9b9f7f159775.js () 9.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} 13.d7ede168008c6b29a08c.js () 8.71 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14.e8d9110fbb4072ef19df.js () 3.67 kB  [rendered]
chunk {15} 15.f6088492832d55965c5f.js () 29.9 kB  [rendered]
```

I use **Workbox 4** to cache bundles at client side using service worker (AppShell).

I use **workbox-build** package to let service worker know which file names (and eventually urls) it has to precache.

**Workbox-build** complements given service worker file with actual filenames when I call **npm run build** (alias for **ng build --prod && node workbox-build-inject.js**, where **workbox-build-inject.js** contains instructions to complement default service worker file).

My **workbox-build-inject.js**:

```js
    const { injectManifest } = require('workbox-build')

    let workboxConfig = {
        globDirectory: 'dist',
        globPatterns: [
            '*.js',
            '*.css',
            'favicon.ico',
            'index.html',
        ],
        swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
        swDest: 'dist/service-worker.js'
    }

    injectManifest(workboxConfig)
    .then(({
        count,
        size
    }) => {
        console.log(`Generated ${workboxConfig.swDest}, which will precache ${count} files, totaling ${size} bytes.`)
    })
```

After building project complemented **service-worker.js** appears in my **dist/** folder.

```js
// We inject manifest here using "workbox-build" in workbox-build-inject.js
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  {
    "url": "0.86bbf5c9edb63f626a71.js",
    "revision": "c57834e89d94af468bc665e4040137ba"
  },
  {
    "url": "10.f7fd6c136990dd6fca53.js",
    "revision": "f26476084572d2c5252d97ffdde9e24a"
  },
  ...
```

This file contains all bundles, but **vendor.17d6b0cb2434f0d8397d.js** and **5.a2ada2def205b6dd2266.js** despite of they match the rule **"*.js"** from the **workbox-build-inject.js**.

So what can be wrong with my build process or workbox config?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the reason for that two files not being included to service-worker.js is size of files (both over 2Mb).

According to workbox-build [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build#full_injectmanifest_config) there's **maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes** parameter:

> **maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes**: Optional Number, defaulting to 2097152
>
> This value can be used to determine the maximum size of files that
>   will be precached. This prevents you from inadvertantly precaching
>   very large files that might have accidentally matched one of your
>   patterns.
>
> Example:
>
> ```js
> // Increase the limit to 4mb:
> maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 4 * 1024 * 1024
> ```

so here's fixed **workbox-build-inject.js**:

```js
    const { injectManifest } = require('workbox-build')

    let workboxConfig = {
        globDirectory: 'dist',
        globPatterns: [
            '*.js',
            '*.css',
            'favicon.ico',
            'index.html',
        ],
        swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
        swDest: 'dist/service-worker.js',
        // Custom size limit
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 4 * 1024 * 1024
    }

    injectManifest(workboxConfig)
    .then(({
        count,
        size
    }) => {
        console.log(`Generated ${workboxConfig.swDest}, which will precache ${count} files, totaling ${size} bytes.`)
    })
```